# How to add a tag with class and attributes inside html file using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there any way to add multiple data-***** attributes and class inside a html file using Javascript. I know how to add a tag inside html file using javascript, and as well as add data-***** attributes. But theres two fact. Is there any shortest way to add it ? and my one is not working.

This is my way to add class and tag using js.

```
<body>
<script>
let add_element = () => {
const template = document.createElement('div');
template.classList.add("mytag");    
document.body.appendChild(template);
}
add_element();
</script>
</body>
```

This is my code. I want to add this tag with all attributes inside HTML file using Javascript. How can I do it ?

```
<span id='an-id' data-page='active' data-page-text='This is page text.' data-print='active' data-print-text='This is print text'></span>
```

How I can add this tag inside HTML file using javascript with all attributes ?

Comment: Like in your example, but additionally using the [`template.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Can you please give me a proper solution plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same as @Mb.Ibrahim said however w3c standards are usually quite open and you can use `-` in your attr name like `data-page-text`

> note: there's no w3c standard that says you can't use `-` in your `data-` name like he says

```js
// <span id='an-id' data-page='active' data-page-text='This is page text.' data-print='active' data-print-text='This is print text'></span>
const span = document.createElement("span")

span.setAttribute('id', 'an-id') // or span.id = 'an-id'

span.dataset.page = 'active' // data-page
span.dataset.pageText = 'This is page text.' // data-page-text
span.dataset.print = 'active' // data-print
span.dataset.printText = 'This is print text' // data-print-text

document.body.appendChild(span)
```

or you can also use `setAttribute` or object to set properties faster.

if you use jquery this is even easier:

```js
$('body').append("<span id='an-id' data-page='active' data-page-text='This is page text.' data-print='active' data-print-text='This is print text'></span>")
```

or

```js
$("<span id='an-id' data-page='active' data-page-text='This is page text.' data-print='active' data-print-text='This is print text'></span>").appendTo('body')
```

Comment: Thanks @Tachibana Shin, I was wondered to see that I can't use multiple dash inside a data-********** value. Because I used multiple times in multiple templates and it works perfectly still now.

Comment: if you use javascript keep in mind that mainstream api like DOM will usually support pascalCase and kebal-case conversion which means for example if the property is `data-page-text` you can use `.data .pageText` (pascalCase) or `.data['page-text']` (kebal-case)

Comment: Again thanks, your solution give me a proper solutions and savad my times. Would you mind if I ask you, How Can I do it using javascript ?

N.B. I've followed your jquery $('body').append("....................) approach.

Comment: you want to append `html` but don't want to use `createElement`?

Comment: you can do it with `.innerHTML` but i really don't recommend it it's easy to get XSS attack even using Fragment it also requires the input data(html) to be really secure full (not user input)

Comment: Oh..... I didnt noticed your js snippets. Sorry and Thanks.

Comment: do you want to use `$().append()` without jquery? I will do it for you in the simplest way

Answer (score 1):

Use `element.dataset` property. For [details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Example:

```js
let add_element = () => {
  const template = document.createElement('span');
  template.classList.add("mytag");
  template.dataset.page = 'active';
  template.dataset.pagetext = 'This is page text.';
  template.dataset.print = 'active';
  template.dataset.printtext = 'This is print text';
  template.innerHTML = "span with data attribute.";

  document.body.appendChild(template);
}
add_element();
```

Note: Follow proper naming convention. Don't use dash on data attribute name.

Wrong: `data-page-text` ,

Correct: `data-pagetext`

Comment: everything is ok. But I want to use dash inside data-attrirbute name.

Comment: Rule violation. Don't do that.

Comment: OK, How can I add an id with value ? You've showed how to add class. I want to add an ID with value

Comment: there is no rule that says `data-page-text` is invalid

Answer (score 1):

You can create some cool reusable DOM helper functions to either,
create a new element

```js
elNew("SPAN", { /* properties */ })
```

add attributes

```js
attr(myElement, { /* attributes */ })
```

get an element

```js
el("#someId")
```

Etc.
Here's an example that creates a `SPAN`, set some initial properties, adds attributes, and insert it into the Document as child of any Element:

```js
// DOM utility functions
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, props) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
const attr = (el, attrs) => Object.entries(attrs).forEach(([k, v]) => el.setAttribute(k, v));

// Task: create element and append to document:

const elSpan = elNew("span", {
  // Add some properties
  id: "some-id",
  className: "active foo bar",
  textContent: "Click me",
  title: "I like titles!",
  style: "color: blue;",
  onclick() {
    this.textContent = "Clicked!"
  }
});

// Add attributes:
attr(elSpan, {
  "data-page": "active",
  "data-pageText": "This is page text.",
  "data-print": "active",
  "data-printText": "This is print text",
  "aria-label": "Some accessibility label",
});

// Insert it wherever you want:
el("body").append(elSpan);

// Test:
console.log(elSpan.outerHTML);
```

Some other helper functions you could create:

```js
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const css = (el, styles) => typeof styles === "object" ? Object.assign(el.style, styles) : el.style.cssText = styles;
```

...you got the point. Helps really into saving keystrokes while maintaining logic and readability.

---

To specifically create a helper function for the `data-*` attributes only, instead of using `.setAttribute()` you could go for [Element.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```js
// DOM utility functions
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, props) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
const data = (el, data) => Object.entries(data).forEach(([k, v]) => el.dataset[k] = v);

// Task: create element and append it to the document:

const elSpan = elNew("span", { textContent: "I'm a span!"});

// Add data-* attributes:
data(elSpan, {
  "page": "active",
  "pageText": "This is page text.",
  "print": "active",
  "printText": "This is print text",
});

// Insert it wherever you want:
el("body").append(elSpan);

// Test:
console.log(elSpan.outerHTML);
```